# php mailer yahoo show sent emails

Tags: phpmailer, yahoo

how can I see the emails that I have sent using my yahoo mail through phpmailer? When I was using the gmail smtp all were saved in my sent folder.  I want the same thing to happen using my yahoo mail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will indeed vary, but if you look at the gmail example provided with PHPMailer, you'll see it has a bit of code that [uploads a message to your IMAP sent messages folder](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps#L74). You'll need to change the IMAP path to match whatever Yahoo uses.